# Mathematical solution for $\sin 3\alpha = 2\sin\alpha$ where $\alpha$ is acute

Tags: trigonometry

I derived the following trigonometrical equation from a real triangle, knowing that the angle $\alpha$ is an acute one:

$\sin 3\alpha = 2\sin\alpha$

Just by eye-balling the equation, and remembering the trigonometric unit circle, I know that:

$\sin 90 = 1 = 2\sin 30 = 2 \cdot 0.5 = 1$

Therefore, $\alpha = 30^\circ$ is a possible solution.
I am unaware of any trigonometric identity to help me simplify this equation in order to get all possible solutions for $\alpha$, and this intuitive solution is the best I can come up with. I plugged this equation into symbolab.com, but their solution seems very long-winded, and I am hoping for the possibility that a simpler one exists.

How can I solve this type of problem when the intuitive approach fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sin 3\alpha = 2\sin\alpha$$

\begin{align}
   \sin(3\alpha)
      &= \sin(2\alpha + \alpha) \\
      &= \sin(2\alpha) \cos \alpha + \cos(2 \alpha) \sin \alpha \\
      &= (2 \sin \alpha \cos \alpha) \cos \alpha 
         + (\cos^2 \alpha -\sin^2 \alpha) \sin \alpha \\
      &= 2\sin \alpha \cos^2\alpha + 
         \cos^2\alpha \sin \alpha - \sin^3 \alpha \\
      &= 3\sin \alpha \cos^2 \alpha -\sin^3 \alpha \\
      &= 3 \sin \alpha(1 - \sin^2 \alpha) - \sin^3 \alpha \\
      &= 3\sin \alpha - 4 \sin^3 \alpha
\end{align}

\begin{align}
   \sin 3\alpha &= 2\sin\alpha \\
   3\sin \alpha - 4 \sin^3 \alpha &= 2\sin \alpha \\
   \sin \alpha - 4\sin^3 \alpha &= 0 \\
   \sin \alpha (1 - 4 \sin^2 \alpha) &= 0 \\
\hline
   \sin \alpha &= 0 \\
   \sin^2 \alpha &= \dfrac 14 \\
\hline
   \sin \alpha &\in \left\{-\dfrac 12, 0, \dfrac 12 \right\}
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

If triple angle relation for sine is known, letting $ \sin \alpha =s$,

$$3 s -4 s^3= 2 s\rightarrow s =(0, \pm \frac12), \quad \alpha=(0, \pm 30^{\circ},  150^{\circ}\pm30^{\circ} ) ..$$

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but I don't understand what this syntax is meant to represent.

Comment: Sorry I should have given it fully, shall edit it in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a lead.

$$\sin(3x) = \sin(2x + x) 
           = \sin(2x)\cos(x) + \cos(2x)\sin(x).$$
Now invoke some double angle magig to get
$$\sin(3x) = 2\sin(x)\cos^2(x) + (1 - 2\sin^2(x))\sin(x).$$
Next, use the pythagorean identities to gete
$$\sin(3x) = 2\sin(x)(1 - \sin^2(x)) +  (1 - 2\sin^2(x))\sin(x). $$
Can you use this?

Comment: This never occurred to me, but it seems to me that there's a lot more work to be done in order to derive the actual angles, isn't there?